# Mathematical derivation of $N(\lambda)d\lambda$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

We all know that in [Rayleigh-Jeans law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law),

$$N(f)df ~=~ 8\pi f^2 df/c^3.$$

How do you derive $N(\lambda)d\lambda$?

I am sort of confused...

Answer (score 1):

by wave theory $ \lambda =vT $ and $ f=1/T $ the waves move to the speed of light so

$ f= \frac{c}{\lambda} $ then  $ d\lambda = -\frac{cdf}{f^{2}} $ simply replace in your equation.

i believe he is referring to $ f= \nu = 2\pi \omega $

Comment: I believe you mean $\omega = 2 \pi f$

Comment: yes i tried this but made a misteake :D sorry